# Visual studio has encountered an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So, I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and in the past week or I'm getting a message from Visual Studio coming up: "Visual Studio has encountered an exception.  This may be caused by an extension."

My ActivityLog.xml reveals logs this as the problem:

```
<entry>
    <record>321</record>
    <time>2012/09/20 16:52:36.126</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. 
Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;1) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: An exception occurred while calling the &apos;OnImportsSatisfied&apos; method on type &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: Cannot activate part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: Cannot get export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.EditorFormatDefinition&quot;)&apos; from part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.EditorFormatDefinition&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSKeyword&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetExportedValueFromLazy[T](Export export)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4`2.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedExportOfTM&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension](Object errorSource, Lazy`1 provider)</description>
</entry>

<entry>
    <record>322</record>
    <time>2012/09/20 16:52:36.202</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;1) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: An exception occurred while calling the &apos;OnImportsSatisfied&apos; method on type &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: Cannot activate part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: Cannot get export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.EditorFormatDefinition&quot;)&apos; from part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.EditorFormatDefinition&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Exports.ExportedClassificationFormatCSSComment&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetExportedValueFromLazy[T](Export export)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4`2.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedExportOfTM&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension](Object errorSource, Lazy`1 provider)</description>
</entry>
```

There doesn't seem to be any specific action that causes this, sometimes it happens when I first fire up VS, sometimes after I leave my desk for awhile and come back.  Also, from the log, it appears to happen right after loading the Visual Studio CSS Editing Package.  I have MVC4 installed, maybe it's a problem with the new CSS (CSS3 I think?)

Anyways, just wondering if anybody had run into this before and had some sort of resolution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20301710/736079

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483057/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-invalid-pointer-visual-studio-2015-updat/42483600 remove this setting from web config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems some VS extension may be causing it to crash. (did you install extension any recently?)

try running VS in safe mode to diagnose the problem.

Run this command and check if VS starts

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

More here

http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/05/16/vs2010-tips-8-got-annoying-visual-studio-2010-error-try-to-run-in-safe-mode/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it still happens in safe mode, same error

Comment: may be try repairing/reinstall VS installation.. that might help.. also may be you can file a bug for VS using tools here .. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/20/the-visual-studio-2012-feedback-tool-a-better-way-to-submit-bugs.aspx

Comment: Yeah I imagine I'll just do that eventually, it's not crashing or anything right now, just more of an annoyance.

Comment: I did reinstall but saw it continue to happen a few times.  It seems to have gone away now though.

Comment: These MEF errors often occur due to a cache folder getting corrupted, clearing said cache folder often solves the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20301710/736079

Comment: @Amitd: does uninstalling the recently installed tool will make VS2010 to work as normal ?

Comment: @MithunM yes it should..  if it doesnt try running in safe mode and then remove extensions one by one..also see if you have all the latest service packs

Answer (score 4):

VS needs Administrator previleges to handle the plugin. So right click VS and click "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR". It solved for me. Try once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and my `ActivityLog.xml` showed the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The
>   composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is
>   provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for
>   more detailed information.
> 
> 1) No
>   exports were found that match the constraint:
>   
> 	ContractName	Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator
> 	RequiredTypeIdentity	Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator
> 
> Resulting
>   in: Cannot set import
>   'Microsoft.Web.Editor.Composition.ComponentLocator(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator)+SingleImporter.Import
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.Web.Editor.Composition.ComponentLocator(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator)+SingleImporter'.
> Element:
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.Composition.ComponentLocator(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator)+SingleImporter.Import
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator")
>   -->  Microsoft.Web.Editor.Composition.ComponentLocator(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.IWebLinterAggregator)+SingleImporter
> 
>
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionResult.ThrowOnErrors(AtomicComposition
>   atomicComposition)
>    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart
>   part)
>    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart
>   part)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.CompositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart
>   part)
>    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices.SatisfyImportsOnce(ICompositionService
>   compositionService, Object attributedPart)
>    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.Composition.ComponentLocator`1.Import()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.LinterUtilities.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_1()
>
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>    at
>   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>    at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.WebLinter.LinterUtilities.IsFileSupported(String
>   fileName)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Lint.ErrorTagger.LintErrorTaggerProvider.CreateTagger[T](ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer)

Solved it by going to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery -> Installed the new version of `Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools`

Answer (score 0):

*(The following solution worked for me)*

I just clicked on the solution file and by default it has tried to open the *.sln file in visual studio 2015 and then I have got the error message "Visual Studio has encountered an exception. This may be caused by an extension".

I had two visual studio version installed - visual studio 2015 & visual studio 2017. I opened the *.sln file in notepad and I could see VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.24720.0 which indicates the solution was created in visual studio 2015.

Then I right clicked the *.sln file and choose the vs 2017 to open it. Then it has open successfully. My best guess is one of the visual studio 2015 extension was not loading correctly and that is why I was receiving that error message.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
Tools->Import and export settings->Reset all settings.

Answer (score -2):

Download web essentials for your VS version. It sorted my issue regarding ActivityLog.xml.
 [Web Essential](http://vswebessentials.com/download)