# Visual Studio 2013 is unable to open the Test Window

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, visual-studio-test-runner

When I open Visual Studio 2013 and load my solution I'm greeted by an error message telling me the Test Window is unable to load.

```
The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) Cannot compose part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal' because a cycle exists in the dependencies between the exports being composed. To break this cycle, consider changing some imports from constructor to property injection.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Data.TestsService+ITestsServiceInternal")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Data.TestsService+ITestsServiceInternal") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal

The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) An operation is not legal in the current state. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131509)

Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost'.

Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.IOpenResult")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.IOpenResult") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal..ctor (Parameter="openResult", ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.IOpenResult")' on part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal..ctor (Parameter="openResult", ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.IOpenResult") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Data.TestsService+ITestsServiceInternal")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Data.TestsService+ITestsServiceInternal") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestsServiceInternal
```

Visual Studio is unable to run tests at all. Closing an re-opening the test window shows the same error.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a corruption in the Component Model Cache.

Close all instances of Visual Studio, then navigate to folder and delete it.

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

Now restart Visual Studio and it should work again.

Comment: I don't have the component model cache in visual studio 2013. How do I fix this error?

Comment: I have the same error and, although I did have component model cache, removing it did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: I will keep that suggestion in my toolbox.  As it turns out, after I removed the component model cache AND THEN EXITED AND RESTARTED VS, the problem was cleared.

Comment: This worked for Visual Studio 2015 for me - replacing 12.0 with 14.0

Answer (score 1):

Deleting **solution.v12.suo** and **solution.suo** can help resolve the problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to best answer (navigate to folder and delete it.    %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache) and it didn't work BUT, based on this method I found the solution which works for me :

navigate to folder and delete it :
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache

Hope I can help some people this way

Answer (score 0):

Just close and re-open Visual Studio (2015) may help.