# The operation could not be completed. invalid pointer - Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image: description]

Getting this error when opening `.cshtml` file:

> The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer

Everything starts after installing update 3 and .Net Core. The mvc core app `.cshtml` files are opening correctly.

Comment: show the code for cshtml file, i.e. the image you posted wont help anyone help you

Comment: I'm talking about all .cshtml files in my ASP.NET MVC 6 project. The same error comes out when I try to attach to application process.

Comment: well the show 1 of them

Comment: Even the default .cshtml views of default MVC project.

Comment: close VS, Open again, then open view. If you get that error, and view wont open at all, i.e. wont show you the contents of the view.... then we take it from there, if you can see the contents of the view past 1 with the error. To  rule out VS, Start a new default project and see if that works.

Comment: A new default project is not works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please, clear the Visual Studio component cache, restart Visual Studio and retry. I suspect that you have some version conflict between components after update. The component cache is located at `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

Comment: sorry, the correct path for visual studio 2015 is %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

Comment: you could also use Mads Kristensen's  extension [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ClearMEFComponentCache)

Comment: I have used it, same thing.

Comment: I had the same problem and Mads Kristensen's extension fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

For those who gone mad like me while trying to fix this issue, the solution for me was in web.config I've set the `webpages:Version` value to `3.0.0.0`. Now i can open cshtml files again.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: This fixed it for me as well